# Why is the id not changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I'm trying to change the colour of text. To do this I change the `id` on the `div` tag ,using JavaScrip,t so different CSS rules apply.

**home.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-original.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function change()
            {
                document.getElementById("part1").className = "part2"
            }
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello.<br />
        <div id="part1">Test test.</div><br />
        <input type='button' onclick='change()' value='Form Checker' />
    </body>
</html>
```

**style-original.css**

```
#part1
{
    color: #FF0000;
}

#part2
{
    color: #7D26CD;
}
```

The colour doesn't change when the button is clicked. What is the problem? Problem is is was changing `className` where as I should be changing the `id`. This was a big fat "[doh](http://commuteorlando.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/image.gif)" moment.

Comment: You're changing the class, not the ID ?

Comment: You realise you're setting the `className`, not `id`, right?

Comment: ^== I'm pretty sure this is the worst way to do this.

Comment: You are trying to change the 'className' not the 'id'

Comment: @Leeish I sure hope you're referring to a comment that has since been deleted and not being to lazy to tell me "a better way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal amount of work to get this to work would be to change the `change()` function to this:

```
document.getElementById("part1").id = "part2"
```

You'd need to keep track of the current id though, or the `change()` function will not find the element again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem. In your javascript function change()

Instead of this line

```
document.getElementById("part1").className = "part2"
```

It should be something like this

```
document.getElementById("part1").id = "part2"
```

That's because you where changing the class name instead of the id of the element.
Take a look at the fixed code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bA6SD/

Answer (score 1):

You're changing a class which has less specificity than an ID. Keeping that ID is over-riding adding a class, though in your sample you've spec'd another ID instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

First, your desired behavior is a little unclear.  That said, here's my interpretation...

In my opinion none of the above are very good options because the don't address the intent of ids / classes.  An Id is meant to be a unique identifier for a specific dom element.  Therefore changing it is not recommended.  I would advise changing your style to reference classes rather than ids.  You can then use the id (part1 and part2) to get each element and assign a class name (ie, redText, purpleText) to the element with the desired styles tied to the class.

```
document.getElementById("part1").className = "redText";
```

The confusing part is that your naming doesn't indicate what your trying to accomplish (what the heck does part1 mean and why is it named that way).  Its always a good idea to name things in such a way that someone else can follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: So the only problem is the naming? I was testing out this concept so I didn't have names to give them. Is there a larger problem you're referring to?

Comment: +1 since your version of my answer is much more detailed :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to change the id? I would suggest that you change the class instead (which is what you currently do in your example). This way you don't need to keep track of the current id and changing the styles is still possible.

Find a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/oqucek/1/edit).